# Replace text that is not within a tag or part of a tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string with bbcode in it: `"[area=A]A[/area] very, [area=good]good[/area] string."`

I need to add bbcode to any word that doesn't already have it. For example, the string above should look like:

```
"[area=A]A[/area] [area=very]very[/area], [area=good]good[/area] [area=string]string[/area]."
```

It also needs to work with accent marks / diacritics (e.g., aquí).

---

String `"[area=A]A[/area] very, [area=good]good[/area] string."` outputs the following as expected:

```
[area=A]A[/area] [area=very]very[/area], [area=good]good[/area] [area=string]string[/area].
```

However, string `"A good string. [area=A]A[/area] very, [area=good]good[/area] string."` outputs:

```
[area=A]A[/area] [area=good]good[/area] [area=[area=string]string[/area]]string[/area]. [area=[area=A]A[/area]]A[/area] [area=very]very[/area], [area=[area=good]good[/area]]good[/area] [area=[area=string]string[/area]]string[/area].
```

I believe this is because substring `"a"` is causing problems.

**Question**: I've tried various approaches with regex and boundaries. I think the best solution is to have a regex that ignore anything inside `[area] word here [/area]` tags, as well as the word that's part of the tag: `[area=word here]`. How can I solve this?

---

Code:

```
var text = `[area=A]A[/area] very, [area=good]good[/area] string.`

var text2 = text

text.split(/[,\s.¡!¿?]+/)
    .filter((v) => {
        if (!v.includes('[area=')) {
            return v
        }
    })
    .forEach((v) => {
        let newFormat = `[area=${v}]${v}[/area]`
        let regEx = new RegExp('(^|\\W)' + v + '(\\W|$)', 'gi') // Custom word boundary
        text2 = text2.replace(regEx, function ($0, $1, $2) {
            return $1 + newFormat + $2
        })
    })

console.log(text2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [the best regex trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) and the [`u` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicode):

```
/
  (             # 
    \[area=     # Match '[area=',
    \p{L}+      # 1+ letters (any language)
    \]          # and ']',
    .+?         # followed by 1+ characters
    \[\/area\]  # '[/area]'
  )             # 
  |             # or
  \p{L}+        # a word.
/gu
```

The first group will be matched, and if it *is* matched, we just need to put it back to the string. Otherwise, we may format the match however we please:

```js
string.replace(
   regex,
   ($0, $1) => $1 ? $1 : `[area=${$0}]${$0}[/area]`
)
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const regex = /(\[area=\p{L}+\].+?\[\/area\])|\p{L}+/gu;

const string = `
[area=A]A[/area] very, [area=good]good[/area] string aquí.
A good string. [area=A]A[/area] very, [area=good]good[/area] string.
[area=A]A[/area] very, [area=good][/area] string.
`;

console.log(
  string.replace(
    regex,
    ($0, $1) => $1 ? $1 : `[area=${$0}]${$0}[/area]`
  )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but did you try your own code? It outputs: `[area=A]A[/area] [area=very]very[/area], [area=good]good[/area] [area=string]string[/area] [area=aquí]aquí[/area].
[area=A]A[/area] [area=good]good[/area] [area=string]string[/area]. [area=A]A[/area] [area=very]very[/area], [area=good]good[/area][[area=area]area[/area]=[area=good]good[/area]] [area=string]string[/area].`

Comment: @user3871 Oops, sorry. That was a C&P error.

Comment: Can you make this work for emojis (emojis only appear inside the tags: `]here[`)? Let's say the string is `"[area=A]A[/area] very, [area=good][/area] string."`; the output should be `"[area=A]A[/area] [area=very]very[/area], [area=good][/area] [area=string]string[/area]."`

Comment: @user3871 Updated (the values after `=` and between tags no longer need to be the same). Check to see if it works.

Comment: Working better. How can I also ignore any text that's within brackets, such as `[ignore me]`?

Comment: @user3871 Add something like `\[[^[\]]*?\]` to the regex as a branch the first group: `/(\[area=\p{L}+\].+?\[\/area\]|\[[^[\]]*?\])|\p{L}+/gu`

Answer (score 1):

With what you want, looks like you should ignore touching words that are either surrounded or being touched by either side of the word with brackets.

Try checking this regex and see if it works for you?

```
(?<![\[\]])\b(\w+)\b(?![\[\]])
```

Match this regex and replace it with `[area=$1]$1[/area]`

Here, `\b(\w+)\b` part avoids partial match of word and `(?<![\[\]])` and `(?![\[\]])` part rejects the words that are either preceded or followed by either `[` or `]`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DTKHnY/1)

Let me know if this works or provide more samples and I can update the regex to cover that. And feel free to change `\w` to the char set you prefer.

**EDIT:**

For matching Unicode characters you can use `\p{L}` instead of `\w` with `u` flag. And since accented letters does not honor word boundary, the regex you can use this following,

```
(?<![\[\]])(\p{L}*\b\p{L}+\b\p{L}*)(?![\[\]])
```

[Updated Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6l03d7/1)

And intext JS demo as Scott Marcus suggested in comments,

```js
const s = 'A good string. [area=A]A[/area] very, [area=good]good[/area] string.aquí';

console.log(s.replace(/(?<![\[\]])(\p{L}*\b\p{L}+\b\p{L}*)(?![\[\]])/gu, "[area=$1]$1[/area]"));
```

Comment: Hi! This works great. Except, it needs to work with accents, like `aquí`. As of now, it does `[area=aqu]aqu[/area]í`

Comment: Please don't post demos at 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Instead, just insert  your code sample into a Stack Snippet (The <> button while editing your question) and the code will execute right here in your answer.

Comment: @user3871: Updated answer to cover accented letters too.

Comment: Can you make this work for emojis (emojis only appear inside the tags: `]here[`)? Let's say the string is `"[area=A]A[/area] very, [area=good][/area] string."`; the output should be `"[area=A]A[/area] [area=very]very[/area], [area=good][/area] [area=string]string[/area]."`

Comment: @user3871: What you are requesting is already working as desired in your comment. [See this](https://regex101.com/r/6l03d7/2)